# deleted functions with a compile time message when they are used

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to restrict operations on a type that has a conversion operator to bool - for example:

```
template <typename R>
Result
operator&&(const R&) {
    STATIC_ASSERT(false, MY_MESSAGE);
    return Result();
}
```

`STATIC_ASSERT` is my wrapper macro around c++11 `static_assert` and a macro-ish c++98 static assert.

I want a somewhat useful message as an error for users that try to use this so making it private or deleting it in c++11 aren't an option.

This however works only for MSVC because of the difference between msvc and g++/clang - with g++/clang the static assert always fires - even when the "deleted" function is not used.

The only thing I've seen that would do the trick is to use an undefined type with it's name as the message as the return type of the template - like this:

```
template<typename R>
STATIC_ASSERT_Expression_Too_Complex_Please_Rewrite_As_Binary_Comparison&
operator&&(const R&);
```

I first saw this [here](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/single_include/catch.hpp#L1246)

Is there any other way to do this in c++98 - a deleted function with a custom message when the user tries to use it?

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. (this was regarding [> this <](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479163) question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `static_assert(false, message)`, `false` is non dependent of template.

You have to make your condition depending of template.

as `static_assert(!std::is_same<T, T>::value, message)`

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just realized the same thing and came up with a solution of my own - ```template <typename T> struct deferred_false { static const bool value = false; };``` and I pass ```deferred_false<R>::value``` to the static assert!